# How to save unzipped content in jszip forEach

Tags: javascript, arrays, promise, push, jszip

Can somebody explain it for me, why zip.files[filename].async('blob') is not getting pushed into the promises list in the below code? console.log(data.length) writes out 0. What am I missing here?

```
 const promises = [];

  var jsZip = require('jszip');
  jsZip.loadAsync(file.object).then(function (zip) {
    Object.keys(zip.files).forEach(function (filename) {
      promises.push(zip.files[filename].async('blob'));
      console.log(promises.length);
    })
  });



  Promise.all(promises).then(function(data){
    console.log(data.length);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It is working this way:

```
  var jsZip = require('jszip');
  jsZip.loadAsync(file.object).then(function (zip) {

    const promises = [];
    Object.keys(zip.files).forEach(function (filename) {
      promises.push(zip.files[filename].async('blob'));
    })

    Promise.all(promises).then(function(data){
      console.log(data.length);
    });
  });
```